# IIS load balancing using ARR

Tags: iis, web, server, arr

I am trying to setup 2 load balanced IIS sites on the same server, with the aim of being able to perform code releases without having to take the site down.

I have IIS installed and have created a server farm containing 2 local websites, test1 and test2. I can hit test1 and test2 directly, however when I hit testfarm, I receive a 502.3 gateway error.

Note: This is all within the same IIS instance, perhaps this is where I am trying to do something which isn't supported?

Comment: Try to use [Troubleshooting 502 Errors in ARR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/troubleshooting-application-request-routing/troubleshooting-502-errors-in-arr) manual.